# How to auto adjust the div tag to wrap around the controls inside it?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have a div tag in which i have other controls. I have given a border to the div through css. I want the div tag to wrap itself around the controls and auto adjust its own size.

```
    .divwrap
    {           
    width: 60%;
    height: 60%; 
    border: 1px solid #66CCFF; 
    vertical-align:middle; 
    margin-left:150px;
    margin-right:300px;
    }
```

Now in the above code I have fixed margins. So if I were to use the same style for a div tag on another page, it would be problem because the controls (inside the div) on another page may be more or less in no. I want the div tag to be like a rubber band that can auto adjust the size when wrapped around something (in this case, an html table with controls).
is this achievable? if yes, how??

Comment: Please don't abbreviate words. It makes your post much harder to read.

Comment: Try using min-height: 60% instead? If not a JSFiddle would be nice with some more complete code.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make a wrapper keep these things in mind

- try not to give it a static dimension.
- don't give any width and height, as it is going to be a little larger than the content over which it is applied
- give percentage value margin and padding:

try this:

```
.divwrap
{
  padding:3%;
  display:inline-block;
  margin:3%;
  border: 1px solid #66CCFF; 
  vertical-align:middle; 
  width:auto;
  position:relative;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manishmishra256/y9ej7/2/).

so now, no matter what the width and height of the child div is, this div will always wrap around it.

Comment: i've updated the fiddle, so kindly click on the fiddle link after refreshing this page.

Comment: why do I have to use a div inside a div? Cant I use both the styles (content & largecontent) in a single class like this <div class="content largecontent"> </div> ?

Comment: ofcourse you can directly apply .divwrap to your content div, but your div might have a width defined, and might already have  padding and margin of its own. that's why you should wrap it in other parent div to make it truly generic.